# curl php is very slow

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

I build the following script to like a facebook status using tokens the problem is the execution take too much time for 5 tokens it take >= 10 seconds

```
foreach ($tokens as $token) 

{           
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/post_id/like');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0;    en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('access_token' => $token));
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Make the requests in parallel with multiquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I let you that function for curl multi request, the input is an array with urls and the output is an array with the results.

For me was very helpful.

For your problem, you just need to put a new input for the tokens and add one param on curl request.

```
function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

      // array of curl handles
      $curly = array();
      // data to be returned
      $result = array();

      // multi handle
      $mh = curl_multi_init();


      // loop through $data and create curl handles
      // then add them to the multi-handle
      foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

        $curly[$id] = curl_init();

        $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        //Set proxy type

        // post? 
        if (is_array($d)) {
          if (!empty($d['post'])) {
            curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
            curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
          }
        }

        // extra options?
        if (!empty($options)) {
          curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
        }

        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
      }

      // execute the handles
      $running = null;
      do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
      } while($running > 0);

      // get content and remove handles
      foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
        $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
      }

      // all done
      curl_multi_close($mh);

      return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You open & close http connection in every iteration :)

Use curl_multi_init():

```
$chm = curl_multi_init();// <---

foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/post_id/like');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0;    en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('access_token' => $token));
    curl_multi_add_handle($cmh, $ch);// <---
}
```

More info about curl_multi_init() you can see on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-init.php)

Answer (score 0):

Each time your're opening a new curl session, setting the same data and sending the request off. Perhaps the following will be a bit faster by declaring data that doesn't change outside the loop.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/post_id/like');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0;    en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101');

foreach ($tokens as $token) {           
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('access_token' => $token));
    curl_exec($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```